# JavaScript - Empty an Array / Object while Passing by Reference Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

to my understanding, both array and objects are Pass By Reference based on the memory address, so if I create another variable and point to the array/object, and mutate any of the values, another value should also be changed.

However, I don't quite understand how it works here. I am pointing to array1 and modifying array1 to empty, why the value at anotherArray does not change?

```js
   var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];  // Created array
   var anotherArray = array1;     // Referenced array1 by another variable
   array1 = [];                   // Empty the array
   console.log(anotherArray);  // Output [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I can understand the below example why the anotherArray becomes [] empty because it is passed by reference, but why the anotherArray still output [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] for the above?

```js
   var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; // Created array
   var anotherArray = array1; // Referenced array1 by another variable
   array1.length = 0; // Empty the array by setting length to 0
   console.log(anotherArray); // Output []
```

Thank you.

Comment: In the first sample you are not modifying the array that `array1` refers to, you are *reassigning* what `array1` refers to. In the second sample you are modifying the array that `array1` refers to

Comment: What is the difference between reassigning vs modifying in the above examples? Thanks

Comment: In order the relationship to exist, both arrays should coexist. If you remove or redefine one of them the relationship goes puff..

Comment: There's no such thing as _pass by reference_ in JS, everything is passed by value. It just so happens that for objects/arrays, the value **itself** is a reference. When you do `array1 = []`, you're simply replacing the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning to a variable *never* changes the object that the variable previously had as value.

Objects -- such as arrays -- only change when you *mutate* them, either through calling a method that does this, or by setting a property.

Here is a visualisation of your first script:

`var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` results in this:

```
  array1
   ↓
  ┌──────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
  │length│ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │
  ├──────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
  │  7   │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │ 7 │
  └──────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

After `var anotherArray = array1` we have this:

```
  array1
   ↓
  ┌──────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
  │length│ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │
  ├──────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
  │  7   │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │ 7 │
  └──────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
   ↑
  anotherArray
```

Then `array1 = []` will create a new array: so there are now two arrays. It also makes `array1` a reference for the newly created array:

```
  array1
   ↓
  ┌──────┐
  │length│
  ├──────┤
  │  0   │
  └──────┘

  ┌──────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
  │length│ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │
  ├──────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
  │  7   │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │ 6 │ 7 │
  └──────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
   ↑
  anotherArray
```

In the second script the assignment to the `length` property (actually a setter) will *mutate* the array. There is no new array created, and the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are lost:

```
  array1
   ↓
  ┌──────┐
  │length│
  ├──────┤
  │  0   │
  └──────┘
   ↑
  anotherArray
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first example, you are actually making a reassignment to array1 as an empty array (and now they are pointing to 2 different arrays in the memory), hence the anotherArray remains unchanged.

```js
 var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];  // Created array
 var anotherArray = array1;     // Referenced array1 by another variable
 array1 = [];                   // Empty the array
 console.log(anotherArray);  // Output [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

In this case, you are actually modifying the array by assigning it's length to 0. since array1 refers to it, it impacts on him as well since they are referring the same array in the memory.

```js
  var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; // Created array
  var anotherArray = array1; // Referenced array1 by another variable
  array1.length = 0; // Empty the array by setting length to 0
  console.log(anotherArray); // Output []
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```js
array1 = [];
```

does not *modify* the array object previously assigned to `array1`. It *assigns* a new (empty) array to the variable; it's not like invoking an operation on the object assigned to `array1`.

To explain it in other words, assume `array1` was the only variable referring the previously assigned array object (`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`). Upon execution of that line (which is a statement, btw) you got lost of the previously assigned array; and it would be garbage collected some time later. This is all because the *assignment operator* is used here and they way its operational semantics is defined in JavaScript.

What is more, your are misusing the concept of *pass by reference* here (a.k.a. *call by reference*); which is a concept that relates to how values are passed to arguments of *functions calls* (or sub routines/procedures, if you prefer speaking of sub routines/procedures rather than functions).

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance you're not actually updating the object that is referenced by array1.
You're replacing the value under the variable name `array1`. `anotherArray` is pointing to the value in memory that was the previous value held in `array1`.

In the second example you're actually updating the underlying value that `array1` and `anotherArray` are both pointing to

Answer (score 0):

In the [assignment operator](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.13.1), `a = x`, **the right-hand side is *evaluated as an expression* (`x`) and the resulting *value* is assigned to `a`**.

This implies that ***`a` never “references” `x`***.

Thus both `a = b` and `a = []` *result in `a` being re-assigned*. It is irrelevant if the right-hand side is a variable (*that is evaluated*) or an empty array literal:

```
var b = [1,2,3] // create and assign array #1
var a = b
// ^— a is assigned the result of evaluating b
// after this assignment a and b “refer to” (read: evaluate to) the same object..
// b -> [1,2,3] #1
// a -> [1,2,3] #1

a.pop()
// ^— modify array object (a.length = 0 would empty the array)
// ..and since a and b refer to THE SAME ARRAY..
// b -> [1,2] #1
// a -> [1,2] #1

var a = [] // create and assign array #2
// ^— a is assigned the result of evaluating []
// after re-assignment both a and b refer to different array objects..
// (the assignment did not alter mutate the original array)
// b -> [1,2] #1
// a -> []    #2

a.push(3)
// ^— modify array object
// ..and since a and b refer to DIFFERENT ARRAYS..
// b -> [1,2] #1
// a -> [3]   #2
```

Calling functions works the *exact same way* as assignments and **there is no “call by reference” in JavaScript**. The *values* that result from the *evaluation of expressions* are supplied as arguments. JavaScript has [Call by (Object) Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) semantics.

tldr: there is no need to talk about “references” in Javascript here, as they add needless confusion and are not even defined (in this manner) in the specification!